# How to performance tune this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Need help in performance tuning the query. The execution plan shows the scan count is too high on SResourceHierarchy and grouprelationship
 tables around in millions. 
I created covering indexes on sresource and matrix goal that reduced the time majorly.
But i want to know if there is any other way of writing query to improve the overall performance even by 1%.

query ::

```
select * from
(SELECT 
sr.rsrcnum, sr.fllnm, isnull(mgr.fllnm,'') as mgrnm, d.actid, d.goaldesctxt ,
    d.cmpltstscd, d.strtdt, d.enddt, dta,
    (select TOP 1 itmtxt from tm.Code where catcd = '12103' and itmcd = d.cmpltstscd and lngcd = 0 and delflg = 0) as Status


from
    TM.matrixgoal d
inner join
    TM.sresource sr on d.rsrcid=sr.rsrcid and sr.delflg=0 and sr.stscd<>1 and sr.rsrcid > 7
left join
    TM.sresource mgr on mgr.rsrcid=sr.mgr1id and mgr.delflg=0 and mgr.stscd<>1
inner join
    TM.resume1 r1 on r1.rsrcid=sr.rsrcid
where
    d.stscd in (3,4) and d.typcd=5009  and d.activeflg=1

        AND (sr.rsrcid IN (SELECT node.empid FROM tm.SResourceHierarchy node JOIN tm.SResourceHierarchy parent ON node.lft > parent.lft AND node.lft < parent.rgt AND node.mgrnum = 1 AND parent.mgrnum = 1  )
or sr.RsrcID IN (select r.rsrcid from tm.resume1 r join tm.grouprelationship g on
  (g.hierarchylvl0 = r.hierarchylvl0 or (g.hierarchylvl0 is null and r.hierarchylvl0 is null))
                and (g.hierarchylvl1=r.HierarchyLvl1 or (g.hierarchylvl1 is null and r.HierarchyLvl1 is null))
                and (g.hierarchylvl2=r.HierarchyLvl2 or (g.hierarchylvl2 is null and r.HierarchyLvl2 is null))
                and (g.hierarchylvl3=r.HierarchyLvl3 or (g.hierarchylvl3 is null and r.HierarchyLvl3 is null))
                and  g.delflg=0 and g.AllowDenyCD='a'))
) temp

ORDER BY
    fllnm, goaldesctxt
```

Comment: Please specify which `RDBMS` you're using. `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?

Comment: what about to show the current plan?

Comment: Whoever named your columns needs shooting... What 'covering indexes' did you create?

Comment: You also have a logic error in your code. You are using top 1 but there is no order by. Without ordering those results you will get a row but you have no way of knowing which one.

Comment: Your query is a performance timebomb. You have so many issues in here it is hard to know where to look. You have a correlated subquery as a column, this means that query has to be executed for every single row in the results. You have a horribly denormalized table (grouprelationship) which is forcing all that awful hierarchy comparison. You also have nonSARGable (not equal) join predicates. Last but not least you have several triangular joins. All this leads up to horrible performance issues. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/

Comment: To try to fix the most severe issue, look into "statistics io" output and try to focus on the table with biggest I/O amounts.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas : I'm using SQL Server

Comment: @SeanLange : In the actual query there is no top 1 but there are other paramters. I just added it to check the performance and limit the subquery by not resulting in more than one row.

Comment: The top is not even on the table for performance, that is a logic error. All the other items I mentioned are huge performance problems.

Comment: @SeanLange :  In my actual query  I have 10 correlated subqueries as columns, I just showed one here for simplicity (Hierarchylvl0 - 9) and same goes in the order by.

Comment: those correlated subqueries as columns are a huge performance bottleneck. Also the nonSARGable join predicates are a performance killer. Then there are the triangular joins. Much of this stems from the denormalized grouprelationship table. Everything would be easier if that was not such a nightmare of a table.

Comment: @SeanLange: How can normalizing that table help further in reducing the said issues? And what made you feel its not in a normalized form?

Comment: It isn't normalized because you have hierarchy level 1, level 2, level 3. That is the definition of repeated columns and violates 1NF. It would help because you don't have to check each column, you would instead check a single column. I would start by getting rid of those correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

It should be use sub query in your query. So it should be performance wise poor.
It is simple sub query run to per main query row. so it is taken much time.
If you improve performance avoid sub query. You use join instead of sub query.

Comment: I agree with Mukesh Kalgude. The two IN sub queries combined with an OR operator takes a lot of performance. Try joins for each of that. Then you can filter and group your result.

Comment: This is good advice. SQL Server, and potentially any RDBMS, will have a hard time optimizing subqueries. Clean syntax describes the data you want and allows the engine to optimize your code so that it can get the data in the fastest way possible. Using subqueries and similarly manipulative syntax takes this ability away from the engine.

Answer (score 0):

To me it look like one big ass single line statement, the only optimation I know if is to try to add a index to the varies tables you are using. that should speed up it's ability to find the data faster

Comment: This should rather be a comment than an answer.

Comment: why the answer is a index ? that is pretty much the only thing to do from this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`.